# Throwing exception from Task.ContinueWith to the main thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, multitasking

In an ASP.NET Core Controller -> I'm trying to rethrow an exception from a Task (in order to log the exception), but I don't understand why it's not caught by the global controller exception filter.

```
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    Task task = GetMyTask();

    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

    task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted && t.Exception != null && t.Exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw t.Exception.InnerException; // Code reached, but this exception is NOT handled by the controller global error handler
            }
        }, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None, continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, scheduler: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() );

    throw new Exception("This exception is handled by the controller global error handler");
    return Ok();
}
```

I don't want to use `await`, since this task is run-and-forget.

Comment: You want Run and Forget, but you want to capture exception. Wut? You can remove `SetSynchronizationContext` as `null` is considered default.

Comment: How about making the action `async Task<IActionResult` and calling the task directly via await?

Comment: @Meikel: OP want's it to run and forget. It's possibly a long running task.

Comment: @FCin, why isn't that possible? (I'm not good at threading concepts). and, removing `SetSynchronizationContext` throws an exception.

Comment: @Meikel, await will wait for this very-long-task as I know..

Comment: @FCin, I want the action to return Ok("someGuid") BEFORE awaiting the task (which take 2 hours), is that possible?

Comment: @FCin: I think OP has a valid use case. OP finds that to handle the exception is of more importance that the wait. I would say: handle/log the exception in the task, rather than await it. ...

Comment: @Hashem: normally in the global exception handler is some sort of logging mechanism. Can't you just put that in your task?

Comment: But I don't understand how that is suppose to work. You want to redirect user to error page if exception happens or do you want to just log the exception?

Comment: I think another architecture would be more reasonable. Why not try starting an process, which does the task. Sounds like your **2 hour task** should not be included in your web application.

Comment: @FCin, just logging it internally, not showing in the UI.

Comment: @Hashem Then why can't you just log it inside `ContinueWith`? Even better. Log it inside `GetMyTask`

Comment: @Meikel, It's actually a PDF generating, it can take seconds, or hours, depends on the parameters, but mostly seconds, and I'm trying to avoid more complexity.

Comment: @FCin, I can, but the global handler has a lot of logic, and I want to understand why it doesn't just catch that exception

Comment: @Hashem how about creating a custom service where you add your "task" and return your request. The service does the long time work in background?

Comment: @Meikel, then I'll need to copy the logging logic again, or?

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought my question is easy to answer by some magic line of code!

Comment: @Hashem 2 things. First of all asp.net core doesn't have SynchronizationContext. You cannot just create it. Secondly your exception is stored inside task returned by `ContinueWIth`. You would have to await it in order to throw it.

Comment: @Hashem You need to only pass the task (`GetMyTask()`) to the service. That's what I thought. The service then has a kind of routine to check every x seconds if a new task came and then executes it in a thread. In the service you can inject `ILogger` and log your exceptions. That's the most maintainable approach IMO.

Comment: Thanks @FCin and Meikel, I will think again for a better approach :)

Comment: @Hashem Global Exception Handlers are good if you want to redirect user when uncaught exception happens. If you want to handle exceptions that you caught, you should use some kind of logger with preferably multiple listeners.

Answer (score 3):

The `await` keyword has pretty much one job: it holds the processing of the code until the task returns. It also unwraps the task, but just as a convenience.

Since you're not using `await` here, that means the calling code moves on and your response it returned while the task is still completing. You're essentially taking it out of the request pipeline context, which then means you cannot catch any exceptions it throws - it's fire and forget, emphasis on the *forget*.

This is not the same thing as doing something "in the background". If you're trying to handle some long-running process outside of the request, the solution to that is to schedule it and have processed by something like an `IHostedService` or a library like Hangfire. That way your request can go ahead an return, but you're now doing the work in a monitored context, where you can do things like throw exceptions. However, you need to be more careful at that point, because the exception still won't bubble up to your global exception handler, because there's no request in play. Instead, you'd need to catch the exception(s) and then notify the client via something like SignalR (websockets), log it, etc. This will also allow you to then potentially monitor the status of the process, and report back to the user (again via SignalR) both progress and completion. None of that is possible by just having a task run without awaiting it.